# Run-time error 91 while getting data from password protected site using vba

Tags: vba

Below is the piece of code I am using:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate "https:......" 
        Do Until .ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
    .document.all.Item("sso_username").Value = "username"
    .document.all.Item("ssopassword").Value = "password"
    .document.forms(1).submit
    End With



   With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
   "URL;https:...." , Destination:=Range("A2"))
      .Name = "q?s=goog_2"
      .FieldNames = True
      .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
      .PreserveFormatting = True
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .BackgroundQuery = True
      .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
      .SavePassword = False
      .SaveData = True
      .AdjustColumnWidth = True
      .RefreshPeriod = 0
      .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
      .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
      .WebTables = "1,2"
      .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
      .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
      .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
      .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
      .WebDisableRedirections = False
      .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With
```

The error is shown for 
  .document.all.Item("sso_username").Value = "username"
Can anybody let me know what i am missing out?

Comment: please try to use `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04"))` instead of `Do until DoEvent` loop...

Comment: add `.busy` to your ie check

Comment: Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:04")) worked. Thanks Maddy Nikam. However only the IE window opens but the data is not returned to the sheet. How do i continue to get output on the worksheet? Is there any way i can link the existing IE window to the query table to get the output on the worksheet?